# port ubuntu kernel to rhel

Tags: ubuntu, rhel, linux-kernel, packaging, development

I need to port ubuntu kernel with HWE to RHEL 9.
I have experience in fedora like systems but not in debian like systems.

I have Downloaded the kernel source using apt source but don't know what to do next because there is single big diff file for patches so I am not able to cherry pick things.

My goal is to:

1. take ubuntu kernel source
2. Add rhel specific customisations
3. package in rpm

Comment: I think you'll find that 1. & 2. are very likely to have many clashes. RHEL is primarily known for being very good at adding backports to LTS kernels, and thus, you get a whole lot of patches that will not apply to the hwe kernel. May I ask which underlying problem you're trying to solve by becoming a one person canonical kernel team?

Comment: @ConstantineA.B. Sir, Ubuntu kernels have wide hardware support then RHEL kernels. So I want to take benefit of Ubuntu kernel inside rhel.

Comment: RH had problems in the past because some other company (very big, starting with the letter O) used its work (but that's what open-source allows). So they made patches applied to their own kernel very difficult to isolate. In contrast, Debian, which has no business model, provides each of its patches to the kernel in a very visible form (and I guess Ubuntu does the same). So indeed, applying RHEL patches looks very difficult since these patches are not obvious. And as @ConstantineA.B. wrote, RHEL backports a lot, which makes patches even less obvious. Might be easier to invert the roles.

Comment: @HemantKumarMeena quotation needed on "Ubuntu kernels have wide hardware support then RHEL kernels. " That just seems plain the opposite of what is true for any given LTS kernel after a few years. If you just want a *newer* kernel, install a newer kernel. By starting to port patches yourself, you're making your level far less stable anyways

Comment: Sir, I need to know how to do it. Decision on whether I should do it is already been made.